# MySQL, choose .ini file

Tags: mysql

I have installed **MySQL** and i am trying to understand few things:

- The is several configuration ***.ini** files, Does the server automatically choose one of them or this files used as templates and i should create my.ini file with my own configuration.
- If i should create my own **my.ini** file so doe's the server automatically look for **my.ini**, Is there a way i can rename the .ini file as i want and configure **MySQL** to look for **myAnother.ini**

If anyone can help me here please i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice. If your original question did not get an answer, see the [FAQ] for guidance on how to edit and improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server will not automatically "search" for any .ini file.

There are multiple levels where the .ini files are specified.

1. During compilating the `configure` script takes certain parameters which can set the default paths where the `mysqld` binary will look for `.ini` files on startup.
2. During startup of the `mysqld` binary it will check for the config files at the defined default paths, unless you specify them via `--defaults-file` or `--defaults-extra-file`.
3. In many distributions there are configuration files to tell the init scripts to pass alternative config file paths to the `mysqld` on startup, using the same parameters as the 2. point.

Howto know the defaults of your compiled binary?

When you do this you see it specified in the first 10 lines of the output: `mysqld --help --verbose | more`

Comment: Thank you so much mauro, I have looking for an answer, have a nice day.